# Unable to bootstrap a node from chef workstation

Tags: chef-infra, bootstrapping, knife

I've an issue with chef , when i try to bootstrap a node .I installed a server and a workstation after i tried to bootstrap a node but it's impossible i got this error message:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gztin.png)

Before bootstrapping i generated a knife.rb for the client with **knife configure client** .

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

You're getting a HTTP 401 error, meaning you are failing to authenticate against the chef server.

To test my knife.rb file I always run a simple command like:

```
knife client list
```

I would expect that fails for you? You need a functioning chef workstation before attempting to bootstrap new nodes.

Comment: It works perfectly , i've toto-validator as result .i Can also ssh the chef server from the workstation .

Comment: I mean that your command worked before , my problem is when i try to bootstrap a node i got an error message .

Comment: @gersen Ahhh, this error message occurs during the bootstrap on the remote machine? In that case the problem could be with "validation_client_name" and "validation_key" settings. The knife bootstrap operation SSH's into the remote node and used these creds to register a new client on the chef server. If they are invalid it might explain the 401. See: https://docs.chef.io/chef_private_keys.html

Comment: @gersen New feature in chef 12.2.0 removes need for validation key see: https://www.chef.io/blog/2015/04/16/validatorless-bootstraps/

Answer (score 0):

Below command for bootstrapping ubuntu linux machine works fine for me.

```
/home/ubuntu/chef-repo/.chef# sudo knife bootstrap -i <.pem_file_of_client_machine> <pubic_IPV4_Address/DNS_of_client_machine> -x ubuntu --node-name <node_name> --sudo --run-list "recipe[<cookbook_name>]"
```

where,

pem_file_of_client_machine            --> private key to connect with client node

pubic_IPV4_IP/DNS_of_client_machine   --> Public IP address/ DNS of the client machine

node_name                             --> String representing node name

cookbook_name                         --> Cookbook that we want to execute on client machine

- Verify Username/Password you are providing or you can try providing private key(.pem file). User should have root permissions on machine.
- Make sure boostraping steps you are performing from **~/chef-repo/.chef** directory where you have private keys of chef server and trusted certs. You can download chef server cert with below command

  ```
  /home/ubuntu/chef-repo# knife ssl fetch
  ```